# How to swap Contents of 2 String Array In Java and Write to another Array

Tags: java, string

This is for my project work and i got stuck on this part.
I have 2 strings mainly;

```
String str = "Testing split me Difficult ";

String str1 = "Testing me split";
```

I have split both str and str1 in 2 arrays according to spaces.They are like this:

```
String[] tokens = ["Testing","Split", "Me", "Difficult"]

String[] tokens1 = ["Testing","me", "Split"]
```

For every 2 index in the 2 array , it applies the percentage function.if percentage are the same, it has to get the 2 string from the second array and and add it to the array list.

Here is what I have:

```
Public class SplitString {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    String str = "Testing split me Difficult;

    String str1 = "Testing me split";
    String[] tokens = str.split("\\s");
    String[] tokens1 = str1.split("\\s");
    for(int i =0;i<tokens.length;i++){
        if(tokens[i].equals(tokens1[i])){
                 arrayList.add(tokens[i]);

        }
        if(Percentage.getpercentagedifference(tokens[i], token[i++]) == Percentage.getpercentagedifference(tokens1[i], tokens1[i++]) ){

                     // I am stuck on how to take the 2 string and swap the contents


                    }
                 else{
                     arrayList.add(tokens[i]);


                 }
}

}
}
```

Percentage.getpercentagedifference is just a function that takes 2 string and returns its percentage difference

Resulting output is something like this:

```
String newlist = "Testing me split Difficult ";
```

For those who don't understand, try looking at this, maybe it helps:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: For every 2 index in the 2 array , it applies the percentage function.if percentage are the same, it has to get the 2 string from the second array and and add it to the array list.

Comment: where did the j variable come from ? (tokens1[j])) ??

Comment: use compareTo() on string you will get +/- or 0 based on that you will come to know the 100% different or partial different & what you want to achieve on this string.

Comment: @N.L.telaviv -Its i Already Edited

Comment: Are the two strings supposed to have same number of tokens? You are getting token length from the first string and then iterating using the same index over the second token set. At times, you may end up with IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Isn't it just `arrayList.add(tokens1[i]);`? Otherwise I have no idea what you're trying to do and you need to explain your example better.

Comment: @ I need to add both string wait,i try to illustrate using a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of us don't understand what you are trying to do. One hint though,

you are using

```
getpercentagedifference(tokens[i], tokens[i++]) // changes i afterwards
```

so you give the method the same string twice. You probably want

```
getpercentagedifference(tokens[i], tokens[i + 1]) // doesn't change i
```

As we still don't understand what you are trying to actually do, here's how to swap 2 strings from 2 different arrays:

```
String[] fruits = new String[]{"Apples", "Bananas", "Melons", "Oranges"};
String[] animals = new String[]{"Cats", "Dogs", "Horses", "Zebras"};
String temp = fruits[1]; // save Bananas
fruits[1] = animals[1];  // replace Bananas with Dogs in fruit array
animals[1] = temp;       // replace Dogs with Bananas in animals array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fruits)); // prints [Apples, Dogs, Melons, Oranges]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animals)); // prints [Cats, Bananas, Horses, Zebras]
```